# Spark Streaming App can not receive msg from Kafka

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I use the following python producer to publish some msg to my kafka topic (I can also receive my published data using a python consumer in jupyter perfectly).

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json,time
userdata={
        "ipaddress": "172.16.0.57",
        "logtype": "",
        "mid": "",
        "name":"TJ"
}
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))

for i in range(10):
    print("adding",i)
    producer.send('test', userdata)
    time.sleep(3)
```

But when I try to run the kafkastreaming example in spark, I do not get anything (I should note that spark is operational in my workstation, since I can run the network streaming example without any issue):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import sys
import os 
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import json


os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.10:2.0.2 pyspark-shell'  

sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "KafkaSTREAMWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,"localhost:2181","raw-event-streaming-consumer",{"test":1})

parsed = kafka_stream.map(lambda (k, v): json.loads(v))
parsed.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Here is the sample of output:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2017-08-28 14:08:32
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2017-08-28 14:08:33
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2017-08-28 14:08:34
-------------------------------------------
```

Note: the spec of my system is as follow:

Ubuntu 16.04
Spark: spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
Jupyter notebook (python 2.7)
Kafka: kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0

I have the following lines in my .bashrc:

```
export PATH="/home/myubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/home/myubuntu/Desktop/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/home/myubuntu/Desktop/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars:$PATH"

export PATH="/home/myubuntu/Desktop/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python:$PATH"

export PATH="/home/myubuntu/Desktop/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark:$PATH"

export PATH="/home/myubuntu/Desktop/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/streaming:$PATH"


function snotebook () 
{
#Spark path (based on your computer)
SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

# For python 3 users, you have to add the line below or you will get an error 
#export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3

#$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]
/home/myubuntu/Desktop/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark  --master local[2]
}
```

Comment: Where are you running this that it doesn't work?

Comment: In my laptop (ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Hi, do you know how to specify kafka bootstrap servers if there are more than one kafka cluster under a zookeeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. With spark spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7, we need to use the following jar:

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0
```